# Problem in adding Icon to a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, icons, jframe, imageicon

I have tried several methods to add an Icon to a JFrame. Every method work perfectly when I run it using the source code.

for example:

```
jframe.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("iconimages/icon.png"));
```

But none of them work when I run it using the jar file. I know the problem is with the path of the image file. How can I solve this?

Edit:

```
public Ui() { 
   initComponents(); 
   setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
   this.setIconImage(getImageIcon("icon.png").getImage());
} 

private ImageIcon getImageIcon(String fileName) {
   String imageDirectory = "iconimages/"; 
   imgURL = getClass().getResource(imageDirectory + fileName); 
   return new ImageIcon(imgURL); 
}
```

I tried this but now I get a null pointer exception.

`--------------------------------------------------------------------------------`

Edit [Solution] : **I found the solution.**

I added `../` to the path additionally and it works perfectly!!! :D

```
 ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon("../imageicons/icon.png");
 this.setIconImage(imageIcon.getImage());
```

Thanks all for try to help me. :)

Comment: This approach of passing a `String` to the `ImageIcon` constructor will not work when the image is in a Jar (as it will probably be when distributed).  paranoid-android provided the correct technique some days ago.  It would be best to figure out how to make it work for your project structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a URL. Like this:

```
 /**
  * Loads and returns an {@link Image} resource. 
  * @param fileName name of the image resource.
  * @return Image as resource.
  */
  public Image getResourceImage(String fileName) {
      String imageDirectory = "images/";
      URL imgURL = getClass().getResource(imageDirectory + fileName);
      Image image = null;
      try {
         image = ImageIO.read(imgURL);
       } catch (IOException e) {}
      return image;
    }
```

Comment: For example, in my jar I had a folder called "images". If your images are all in the root directory of the jar, you won't need the imageDirectory String.

Comment: Take another look at my answer. I gave you a loader method for an ImageIcon, not an Image - so I fixed it so that it loads an Image instead. Use ` and indentation when using code in a comment. :)

Comment: @Bhathiya  Please update your question (edit it) with the new code, rather than post the code in a comment.  It becomes a mess!

Comment: If you're getting a null pointer, try `System.out.println(imgURL);` right before you return the image. If the URL is null, take a closer look at where your file is and where you're looking for it.

Comment: +1 for editing your answer.  I've deleted the comment that is now noise.  :)

Comment: I also have the folder iconimages inside my jar file. But still URL is null even run using the source code.

Comment: Just re-check to see if you're using the code in my answer? And is your icon.png in your iconimages folder?

Comment: I think the URL is null because it can't find the file. Try taking out the imageDirectory string and for the filename use "iconimages/icon.png". So `this.setIconImage(getResourceImage("iconimages/icon.png"));`

Comment: Thanks. I found the solution. I edited the question with the answer.

Comment: @Bhathiya: Accept it as the correct answer, if you please. :)